# Jquery colorbox: change cursor from hand to pointer shape

Tags: jquery, shapes, mouse-cursor

How can the hand shape mouse pointer showing on mouse over of parent window be changed to a different pointer shape in jquery colorbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following changes of cursor type in jquery.colorbox.js has resolved my issue

```
$overlay.css({ "opacity": +settings.opacity, "cursor": settings.overlayClose ? "default" : "default" }).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your colorbox' CSS, specify

```
cursor : hand;
```